# Tomcat Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.lang.SecurityException, org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, saxparser

While deploying a .war file in the tomcat 8.5.16 version, I get following error:

> **Exception**
>
> **java.lang.SecurityException: AuthConfigFactory error:**
>   **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:85)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1205)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1195)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:469)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Root Cause
>
> **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:65)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1205)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1195)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:469)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Root Cause
>
> **java.lang.SecurityException**: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException:
>   SAX feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings' not
>   recognized.
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.PersistentProviderRegistrations.loadProviders(PersistentProviderRegistrations.java:66)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.loadPersistentRegistrations(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:329)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:69)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:65)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1205)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1195)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:469)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Root Cause
>
> **org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException**: SAX feature
>   'http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings' not recognized.
>     oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.setFeature(JXSAXParserFactory.java:230)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.setFeature(Digester.java:478)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.PersistentProviderRegistrations.loadProviders(PersistentProviderRegistrations.java:62)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.loadPersistentRegistrations(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:329)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:69)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:65)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1205)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1195)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:469)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Note The full stack trace of the
>   root cause is available in the server logs.

Any help how it can be resolved ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **`$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.properties`**

Set following 4 jars at the dead end:

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl
```

This sets, your catalina environment to include required .jars.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be useful for somebody.

I had exactly the same problem as @Om Sao when running Tomcat in an Azure PaaS WebApps environment. For me, the problem was that there was no ROOT directory under `site/wwwroot/webapps`. When the ROOT directory was added (I am not sure what - if anything - actually needed to be in the ROOT directory to make it work) then the problem disappeared.

Another time I had this problem was when I uploaded my application to the ROOT directory by accident by clicking "Deploy to Root" in Azure (when doing Azure/Publish as Azure Web App in Eclipse)

[image]